# Getting this common crystal tester to measure very high frequency crystals, resonators & oscillators

Tags: oscillator, crystal, frequency-measurement, test-equipment

So these common [crystal tester types](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004716060545.html) have 50MHz as their frequency counting ceiling. How do I make them be able to measure the fastest crystals, resonators & oscillators (the latter two going up to single digit Ghz')? Is it a matter of multiplying the frequency of the tester by slapping on a CMOS crystal frequency multiplier subcircuit?

Maybe not. Because even then, I can see that there seems to be multiplexing on resistors, more of it to be added as it stretches to higher ranges & some programming as well.

Opinions on going about this?

Comment: Site rule about this type of question: **Opinion-based** $$$$

*This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.*

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I doubt there is a trivial modification you can make to allow you to measure GHz signals.

Comment: This so-called "crystal tester" is a frequency counter. It just uses an oscillator to freerun the crystal and counts the number of pulses. So *"Is it a matter of multiplying the frequency of the tester?"* No, what you want is *dividing* the frequency, not multiplying (but beware that you would be working with GHz circuits) to make it countable. Next, if you need to test oscillators seriously, you likely need a benchtop GHz frequency counter, an RF spectrum analyzer, or a Vector Network Analyzer. None is cheap, but second-hand instruments can often be found at much lower prices.

Comment: @比尔盖子: Alright, so we divide the frequency of the the crystals, resonators or oscillators being tested, scale it down... But, what I was saying is to *multiply* the frequency of the *tester*, not the *testee* (crystal, resonator or oscillator). Maybe if you read more thoroughly what I wrote up there, you wouldn't type away as you did.

Comment: @TempusNomen It makes no sense to "multiply the frequency of the tester"; there are limits to how fast things can be run and this is likely running near its limit. Dividing the frequency of the oscillator, on the other hand, makes perfect sense.

Comment: @TempusNomen I believe Andy is responding to the fact that you specifically ask for "Opinions on going about this". That sounds like you're looking to solicit opinions on how one might go about doing this.

Comment: @TempusNomen This "frequency counter" appears to use a PIC microcontroller to count the number of pulses from the oscillator-under-test and compares it with its own clock (a design similar to https://www.qsl.net/dl4yhf/freq_counter/freq_counter.html). How fast can the hardware counter on PIC microcontroller run? Even when running out-of-spec, not faster than 100-200 MHz as a quick web search suggests, not 1 GHz. Not to mention that the hardware counter already uses internal prescalers to divide input frequencies. Adding more external frequency division is all but a natural design choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up upon seeing the schematic of the referred crystal tester:
[image]
https://www.electronicszone.it/projects/frequencycounterbypic628_en.php

It's so much easier & streamlined to buy a dedicated frequency meter (going into GHz) & construct a subcircuit (highlighted in red) that will oscillate the vibration of the item (crystals, resonators & oscillators) to go to said frequency meter.

The problem is said subcircuit. Being a Colpitts Oscillator, it requires an LC tank, with very, very low LC value (for GHz). I've touched upon this subject & I think I'll solve it with another RL solution on my own.

Comment: Hard to believe I was afraid of those 8 resistors. Turns out they're just current limiters for the 7-segments.